# pass arguments into javascript method from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript method that checks the following condition

```
method(selection1,selection2)
{
    if(selection1=="yes")
    {
    //Do something
    }
    if(selection2=="yes")
    {
    //Do something
    }
}
```

now i pass arguments from code behind like this

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "id", "method('" + selection1 + "," + "'" + selection2 + "')", true);
```

Here selection is a string variable

```
string selection1="Yes"
```

But the desired functionality doesn't work out. I know the javascript is correct because when i use hardcoded arguments then the javascript runs.

Kindly help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it this way:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyScript", javascript:method('"+selection1+"','"+selection2+"')", true);
```

This will call the function and send the params as well, just be sure about the case that use in the string.

Comment: Actually when i tried doing it your way, i saw that i have missed a single quote in the call. That was the issue. Either way of calling is fine.(yours and mine)

Comment: I don't have that much reputation :P

Answer (score 0):

Your code missing `'` ending quotes for first string argument.
Use like this

```
"method('" + selection1 + "', '" + selection2 + "')"
```

For comparison to be success the string must be exactly equal. `selection1` value should be `"yes"` for the condition to be success